# IOS Combine Interoperability With MySQL & Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ios, mysql, ruby-on-rails, swift, combine

I am new to programming and am building an app with SwiftUI and want to learn Ruby on Rails for the backend and skip Core Data ( I heard it is not necessary and could use MySQL)

Does Combine inter-operate with MySQL / Ruby on Rails? Does it need to?

I am just trying to establish the simplest tech stack to learn and want to make sure everything works together.

Thank you!

Comment: Combine - a client-side framework - has nothing to do with Ruby or MySql - a server-side stack.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Swift or Combine, so there may be better ways of integrating Rails.

But there's a reliable way that works with most languages and applications: use Rails to create a REST API, then have the app make HTTP calls to the Rails server.  Let Rails manage the database, and describe your objects/records in JSON.

`rails new --api ./my_app` will give you a small-scale Rails app that's focused on handling API calls.

You'll basically end up writing two projects, one for the Swift/Combine client, one for the Rails server.  But separating the two means you can write other clients (a website, for example) with little additional hassle as your project grows.

Comment: The risk here if you're just stepping into programming is that you're fanning out way to wide if you try to learn Swift and Ruby at the same time on completely different platforms. Focus on learning one thing for now and circle back to server side development later.

Comment: Much appreciated Max! Thank you